# How to draw out a JLabel? - Java

Tags: java, class, drawing, jlabel, graphics2d

I want to draw out a JLabel in a "public void paint(Graphics g) {}" and all that stuff. How do I take a JLabel from outside of the class (within the main method) and draw it out in the paint method?

```
static JLabel drawThisOut = new JLabel("draw this out");
public static void main(String[] args) {
    class paintJLabel extends JComponent {
         public void paint(Graphics g) {
             //what goes here to draw the JLabel?????
         }
    }
}
```

And no, I cannot just use the regular JLabel instead of drawing it out. I need to draw something else over the JLabel and I assumed this was the most efficient way to do it. (Is there a more efficient way?) Any help at all would be greatly appreciated. Please be specific. Thanks!

Comment: *"I need to draw something else over the JLabel I need to draw something else over the JLabel"* I could think of a number of ways you could draw over a label, but which one might be useful would depend on what you're doing - Also, I'm not sure what "draw out" means in this context

Comment: `JLabel` has support for displaying both `icon` and `text`. You could use `GridBagLayout` and `Border`s to mess about with offsets and positioning as one thought. You could use a `JLayeredPane` and/or the `glassPane` or even `JLayer`

Comment: Nope - excuse me for not wanting to waste my or your time on something which is unclear

Comment: Could you take 5 minutes to provide a better explanation of what you are trying to achieve - it will narrow down the available solutions - and no, it would take a lot more then 5 minutes to put an example together of all those options - which probably won't do what you want because you've not explained your overarching issue. And please, I've been on SO for over 4 years and have spent plenty of time helping people, I'd like to help you, but you need to help me first. The question is already unclear in it's current state

Comment: You might want to delete some of your comments as some of them are not appropriate or even down-right rude (talk about biting a hand that would feed you!).

Answer (score 0):

In the "simplest" terms, you could use a `Border` of some kind, the following presents a custom rounded border, but the concept is relatively simple

[image: Rounded Border]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.geom.RoundRectangle2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.AbstractBorder;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            JLabel label = new JLabel("This is a test");
            label.setBorder(new RoundedBorder(Color.BLACK, 20));
            add(label);
        }

    }

    public class RoundedBorder extends AbstractBorder {

        private final Color color;
        private final int gap;

        public RoundedBorder(Color c, int g) {
            color = c;
            gap = g;
        }

        @Override
        public void paintBorder(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION_QUALITY);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_COLOR_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_COLOR_RENDER_QUALITY);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_DITHERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_DITHER_ENABLE);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_FRACTIONALMETRICS, RenderingHints.VALUE_FRACTIONALMETRICS_ON);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL, RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE);
            g2d.setColor(color);
            g2d.draw(new RoundRectangle2D.Double(x, y, width - 1, height - 1, gap, gap));
            g2d.dispose();
        }

        @Override
        public Insets getBorderInsets(Component c) {
            return (getBorderInsets(c, new Insets(gap, gap, gap, gap)));
        }

        @Override
        public Insets getBorderInsets(Component c, Insets insets) {
            insets.left = insets.top = insets.right = insets.bottom = gap / 2;
            return insets;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isBorderOpaque() {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

You could also use a custom component.  This provides you with the added benefit of been able to "fill" the shape with your own background color, but is, otherwise, essentially the same thing

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.geom.RoundRectangle2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.AbstractBorder;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            JLabel label = new JLabel("This is a test");
            label.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
            RoundedPane pane = new RoundedPane();
            pane.add(label);
            add(pane);
        }

    }

    public class RoundedPane extends JPanel {

        public RoundedPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION_QUALITY);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_COLOR_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_COLOR_RENDER_QUALITY);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_DITHERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_DITHER_ENABLE);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_FRACTIONALMETRICS, RenderingHints.VALUE_FRACTIONALMETRICS_ON);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL, RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE);
            g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2d.draw(new RoundRectangle2D.Double(0, 0, getWidth() - 1, getHeight() - 1, 20, 20));
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Sorry if I responded rudely earlier.